# Refrescar Gridview android

Tags: java, android, programación-móvil

Tengo una clase en la que defino un gridview que se carga mediante un Jsonrequest desde un servidor remoto sobre el cual puedo realizar peticiones como mostrar, editar, eliminar. Al momento de editar y eliminar quisiera que se refrescara el gridview automaticamente mediante un metodo refresh he intentado llamar el metodo desde otra clase pero no consigo hacerlo. por favor cualquier ayuda agradezco.

clase principal:

```
public void getData() {
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Cargando categorias...", "Un momento por favor...", false, false);

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URL + "300",
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        loading.dismiss();

                        showGrid(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        );

        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        //Adding our request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }


    public void showGrid(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        //Looping through all the elements of json array
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            //Creating a json object of the current index
            JSONObject obj = null;
            try {
                //getting json object from current index
                obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                ModelCat modelo = new ModelCat(obj.getString(TAG_ID), obj.getString(TAG_NAME), obj.getString(TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                //getting image url and title from json object
                list_data.add(modelo);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //Creating GridViewAdapter Object
        AdapterCat gridViewAdapter = new AdapterCat(this, R.layout.grid_item, list_data);

        //Adding adapter to gridview
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    }
```

clase Adaptador desde donde realizo las operaciones de CRUD:

```
 private void DeleteServerCat(String idcat) {

        displayLoader();


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                HTTP_JSON_DELETE + idcat,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        hideDialog();
                        // pd.hide();

                        Categorias categorias = new Categorias();

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        categorias.getData();


                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (error != null) {

                            hideDialog();

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No hay conexión a internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

        Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(stringRequest);

    }
```

las operaciones CRUD las realizo desde el adaptador del gridview desde se obtiene el id de cada elemento el cual se envia por peticiones POST al servidor para que edite o elimine el registro correspondiente. Al momento de realizar la operacion necesito que se refresque o actualice el grid y muestre los datos en tiempo real de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo que tu adaptador hereda de "BaseAdapter" y de acuerdo con: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html
**adapter.notifyDataChanged();** debería de actualizar los elementos del GridView.

**PERO** lo que logro observar en tu código es que CREAS un nuevo adapter llamado "gridViewAdapter" y lo agregas a tu gridview. Esto puede ser el problema ya que no deberías de colocar un nuevo adaptador si más bien manipular la lista "list_data" de tu adaptador, es decir añadiendo elementos a lista "list_data", eliminando elementos elementos a lista "list_data" o actualizando datos de algún elemento de la lista "list_data" y luego notificar al adapter que la lista, de la cual se basa para construir sus elementos ha cambiado, esto lo logras invocando: **adapter.notifyDataChanged();**

Ahora, si lo que deseas es cambiar por completo el adaptador del gridview, revisa esta otra respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458814/how-to-update-gridview-after-changing-adapter-data posiblemente sea lo que buscas.